# The best software to create book?

Tags: open-source, markdown, ebooks, latex, books

I want to start writing book and I'm interested what software is available on the web.

It should have:

- Be open source.
- Easy to write.
- Create LaTeX.
- Easy to format.
- Write in easy syntax.

Comment: Should run on which OS? Or should it be a web-app? What eBook standards/formats must it support – or is LaTeX the target format (never heard about eBooks being *published* in LaTeX – they're usually EPUB, MOBI, LIT, PDF etc.; so maybe the `ebooks` tag is misleading, and should be removed from your question)? Is the target really an eBook (as the tags suggest), or is it intended for "print only"?

Comment: Please edit both your Question and its title to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [gitbook-plugin-build](https://github.com/urosjarc/gitbook-plugin-build)

> Extends gitbook build system with pandoc converter.

### Description

**GPB** (gitbook-plugin-build) extends [gitbook](https://www.gitbook.com/)
build system with [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) converter. Pandoc is your
swiss-army knife when it comes to coverting files. **GPB** use pandoc
build system to convert and compile your book in variety of formats:

- **TeX formats**: LaTeX, ConTeXt, LaTeX Beamer slides
- **HTML formats**: XHTML, HTML5, and HTML slide shows using Slidy, reveal.js, Slideous, S5, or DZSlides.
- **Word processor formats**: Microsoft Word docx, OpenOffice/LibreOffice ODT, OpenDocument XML
- **Ebooks**: EPUB version 2 or 3, FictionBook2
- **Documentation formats**: DocBook, TEI Simple, GNU TexInfo, Groff man pages, Haddock markup
- **Page layout formats**: InDesign ICML
- **Outline formats**: OPML
- **PDF via LaTeX**
- **Lightweight markup formats**: Markdown (including CommonMark), reStructuredText, AsciiDoc, MediaWiki markup, DokuWiki markup, Emacs Org-Mode, Textile

Writing books with this plugin will be peace of cake. And here cake is **not a lie**!

### Homepage

For more informations please visit projects official homepage.

> https://urosjarc.github.io/gitbook-plugin-build

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `Madoko`?

- http://www.madoko.net

  - http://www.madoko.org/reference.html (or `*.pdf`)

You can connect to your local documents offline via the npm package `madoko`.

Also, there's a video introduction from Microsoft Research, do a search for it.

Comment: Please describe the input syntax. Also, what output formats are available? And what is the license?

Answer (score 0):

OpenOffice is all of those things minus LaTeX creation, though I have seen workflows for converting LaTeX so it can be imported.

It's really just trying to be an open source version of Microsoft Word.

Comment: What output formats are available? Only PDF?